# isset() issue? jQuery Ajax PHP Log-In

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My code should be referencing the login_process.php page which I believe it is but it's not returning ANYTHING.  Whether it be an error or a success message.  I don't see what's wrong and tried a few different things to get it to work.  When I echo something outside of the `isset($_POST['login'])` it shows.  But inside of it, shows nothing.  That's what's leading me to believe it's an issue with that...  But i'm not too sure.

PHP Code:

```
<?php 
ob_start();
require 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {

    $date = date("F j, Y, g:i a"); 

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
    // VARS
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $username = strip_tags($username);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);

    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = strip_tags($password);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    // SELECT DB
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ( mysql_error() );

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) != 0) {
         session_start();
         $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
         $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "true";
         $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
         $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
         header("refresh: 2; bet_gg.php");

         echo '<div class="alert success hideit" style="width: 50%;">
         <p> Success.  You will be redirected.</p>
         <span class="close"></span></div>';


    } else {
         $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "false";



                 echo ' 
        <div class="alert error hideit" style="width: 50%;">
        <p>There was an error with your log-in.</p>
        <span class="close"></span>
        </div><!-- End error -->';



         }
    }

   ?>
```

HTML Code:

```
    <form action="login_process.php" method="POST" id="myForm">   
    <div class="two-thirds column">
      <div class="who">
        <h2 class="title">Log-In<span class="line"></span></h2>
       <div class="form-box">
        <label>Username <small>(required)</small></label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="text">
      </div><!-- End Box -->
      <div class="form-box">
        <label>Password <small>(required)</small></label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="text">
      </div><!-- End Box -->
      <div class="form-box">
        <button type="submit" clas="button medium color sub" name="login" class="button medium color sub" value="Log-In">Log-In</button>
      </div><!-- End Box -->
        <br /><br />
      </div>
    </div><!-- End who we are -->
    <span id="result"></span>
   </form>
```

jQuery code:

```
    $("#sub").click( function() {
 $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
         $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
         function(info){ $("#result").html(info); 
   });
});

$("#myForm").submit( function() {
  return false; 
});
```

Comment: Why do you call `ob_start()` at the beginning?

Comment: I was having a header issue before and someone told me to put ob_start(); at the top of my log-in script.

Comment: what is this double class attribute `<button type="submit" clas="button medium color sub" name="login" class="button medium color sub" value="Log-In">Log-In</button>`, and in your javascript code your using `$("#sub")` since there is attribute `id` in that button

Comment: I took it out but that wasn't the issue, of course..

Comment: Well, have you looked up what `ob_start()` actually does when someone told you to put it there? http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php `This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead the output is stored in an internal buffer.`

Comment: You need `ob_start()` to prevent output before `header("refresh: 2; bet_gg.php");`, since headers must be sent before anything else, but you'll need a `ob_end_flush();` after the header instruction and in the else branch (but that's just a workaround, it should work without it unless the `db.php` is echoing something.)

Comment: I looked it up now and took it out and that's not what's causing my code to not work.  I added ob_end_flush(); to the end of my script and it's still not returning anything.

Comment: try submitting the form without javascript

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a `#sub`, but the apparent submit button has `name="login"`.  Per the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

> No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button

Check `isset($_POST['username'])` instead.

Comment: I put isset($_POST['username'] && isset($_POST['password']) and it works but it doesn't redirect on success.

Comment: @user2555621 you would need to redirect in the ajax response; the refresh header is ignored

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript code to something like this

```
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.post( $(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize()+"&login=1", function( info ) {
    $("#result").html(info);
  }); 
});
```